# SQL Grouping Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am running the below SQL but keep getting the error:-

> 'Column 'SRVS.dbo.BTQGLDistributionsWithProjectCodesHM.AccountNo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

The code I am running is:-

```
SELECT         AccountNo, 
           TransDate, 
           JournalNo, 
           AuditTrail, 
           Description, 
           JnlAmount, 
           ACTINDX, 
           CONTRACTNAME, 
           PAPROJNUMBER,GROUPING(PAPROJNUMBER) as PAPROJNUMBER, 
           SUM(PAFeebillamount) as total
FROM       SRVS.dbo.BTQGLDistributionsWithProjectCodesHM
GROUP BY   PAPROJNUMBER with rollup
ORDER BY   GROUPING (PAPROJNUMBER
```

Can anyone point me in the correct direction on this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! And if you post error messages, **PLEASE** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `GROUP BY` statement, anything not using an aggregate must be specified in the `group by` clause.

```
SELECT     AccountNo,  
           TransDate,  
           JournalNo,  
           AuditTrail,  
           Description,  
           JnlAmount,  
           ACTINDX,  
           CONTRACTNAME,  
           PAPROJNUMBER,GROUPING(PAPROJNUMBER) as PAPROJNUMBER,  
           SUM(PAFeebillamount) as total 
FROM       SRVS.dbo.BTQGLDistributionsWithProjectCodesHM 
GROUP BY   
       AccountNo,  
       TransDate,  
       JournalNo,  
       AuditTrail,  
       Description,  
       JnlAmount,  
       ACTINDX,  
       CONTRACTNAME,
       PAPROJNUMBER with rollup 
ORDER BY   GROUPING (PAPROJNUMBER)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to include all columns in the `SELECT` statement that isn't included in an aggregate function in the `GROUP BY` clause like so:

```
SELECT AccountNo, TransDate, 
  JournalNo, AuditTrail, Description, 
  JnlAmount, ACTINDX, CONTRACTNAME, 
  PAPROJNUMBER, GROUPING(PAPROJNUMBER) as PAPROJNUMBER,
  SUM(PAFeebillamount) as total 
FROM SRVS.dbo.BTQGLDistributionsWithProjectCodesHM 
GROUP BY 
  AccountNo, TransDate, 
  JournalNo, AuditTrail, Description, 
  JnlAmount, ACTINDX, CONTRACTNAME, 
  PAPROJNUMBER
with rollup 
ORDER BY GROUPING (PAPROJNUMBER)
```